# How to read data from a serial port in Windows using python?

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In windows 10 I am trying to read the output of an attached serial device.

Using `hterm` I am able to see the data on serial port `COM5`. So the serial port works fine.

Now using WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04.3) I am  running the following python script

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM5", baudrate=115200)
```

which fails with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 6, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial("COM5", baudrate=115200)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port COM5: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'COM5'
```

I also tried to use the suggestions posted in [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/connecting-usb-devices-to-wsl/) at attach the USB port on which the serial device is connected to, to WSL.

The command `usbipd wsl list` in a windows powershell shows then

```
8-3    0403:6001  USB Serial Converter                                          Attached - Ubuntu-20.04
```

But when then running the same python code in WSL2 gives the same error.

So how to fix this problem so I am able to just read all data from the serial port with python?

Comment: "*In windows 10 ... I also tried to use the suggestions posted in this article*" -- That article specifies Win 11, but you're using Win10! Your title ("*in Windows*") does not seem to match the actual environment ("*using WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04.3)*") of the reported problem. Regardless, Linux or WSL would not use a Windows serial port name, but rather something like **/dev/ttyS**n for a UART and **/dev/ttyUSB**n for a USB-to-serial adapter.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like `/dev/ttyUSB0` finally works!

Comment: Alex, the answer I did should resolve your issue, regardless of the platform, since it will detect ports like `/dev/tty*` and `COM*` depending on the USB identifier your device has. Also implements error handling, timeout and better locking thanks to the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the following script.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM5", baudrate=115200, timeout=1)`
while True:
   data = ser.readline()
   print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] Code updated and tested as per locking remarks[/EDIT]

I generally use a solution where I just identify the port name from USB VID:PID data.
This allows me to not hard code any com port name.

You must begin searching for the port name corresponding to your USB device (see `find_device()` below).

You should also use locks on your serial port while reading so you don't get multiple concurrent accesses, which especially on Windows will create permission errors. See `with LOCK` context manager for locking the serial reads.

Code has been tested from Python 2.7 to 3.11 on both Windows and Linux.

Of course you can adapt the serial port settings and perhaps the size of read bytes and/or timeout.

```py
import serial.tools.list_ports
import serial
from threading import Lock

# Your USB SERIAL DEVICE identification
USB_VID = "0x0403"
USB_PID = "0x6001"

SERIAL_SETTINGS = {
    "baudrate": 115200,
    "bytesize": 8,
    "parity": "N",
    "stopbits": 1,
}

LOCK = Lock()


def find_devices():
    # type: () -> List[str]
    """
    Find all COM ports corresponding to your USB device
    """
    _device_ports = []
    for port in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
        if port.vid == int(USB_VID, 16) and port.pid == int(USB_PID, 16):
            _device_ports.append(port.device)
    return _device_ports

def read_device(device) -> str:
    # type: (str) -> str
    try:
        with LOCK:
            with serial.Serial(device_port, timeout=1, **SERIAL_SETTINGS) as ser:
                result = ser.read(size=64).decode('utf-8')
                if len(result) == 0:
                    return None
                else:
                    return result.strip("\r\n")
                return result
    except serial.SerialException as exc:
        error_message = "Cannot read serial port {}: {}".format(device_port, exc)
        print(error_message)  # or log it
        raise OSerror(error_message)


for port in find_devices():
    data = read_device(port)
    print(data)
```

Hope this helps.
More examples of serial reading can be found in a library I wrote for reading USB temperature sensors, see [this](https://github.com/netinvent/dogratian_usb_sensors)

Comment: Following the statement `yield` in function  `_with_Lock()` I don't see how `LOCK` could be `None`. The function also does not appear to be thread-safe because of a race condition.

Comment: Indeed I forgot the global lock initialization which is None, code updated.. What makes you think this example isn't thread safe ?

Comment: Thread loses control following `if LOCK is None:` but before it executes `LOCK = Locck()`. Thread 2 executes `_with_Lock` and loses control back to thread 1 after executing `LOCK.acquire()`. Thread 1 then proceeds to overlay original `LOCK` global with a new instance. Then when thread 2 does `LOCK,release()` it is not the same lock it acquired and there will be too many `release` calls just for starters. It would seem this function is a critical section that needs to run under a lock from the beginning -- which is ridiculous. (more...)

Comment: For multithreading you can just create a global lock with `LOCK = Lock()` at the global level. Then your function body is just: `LOCK.acquire(); yield; LOCK.release()`. You should also do this with `try/finally` so that the lock is releases even on an Exception. Of course, people can just directly execute `with LOCK: some-citical=section` wherever they need to serialize something. It's not always necessary to lock a complete function and it might be wasteful to do so.

Comment: I should add that you are creating a context manager for a `Lock` instance, but a `Lock` is already a context manager and so this makes no sense even if `_with_lock` were implemented correctly. You should just have a global `LOCK = Lock()` and then replace wherever you have `with _with_lock():` with 'with LOCK:`. See [demo](https://ideone.com/kY8SiE) showing the race condition and the possible errors.

Comment: Indeed using `with LOCK` directly since it's already a context manager makes sense. Updated the code after a quick test run on Python 2.7 and 3.10 with a USB serial device. Thanks for your advice ;)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would get this to work in Ubuntu 20.04.3 first.

Just download a Virtual Machine of Ubuntu, install it (in a VM environment (or real machine if you have one spare) ) and test.

WSLx is really good but it still has some teething problems.

If you know it passes in a real (or VM) Ubuntu install then you are most of the way there.

I always do this as WSLx can have some weird quirks I have found. It shouldn't for note but it does, especially when it comes down to external hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Ubuntu, you can't use the Port-Names used by Windows. In Ubuntu Port names usually are in the format of `dev/ttyUSB` followed by the number of the port (`dev/ttyUSB0`).